# Out Of Memory error in JUnit test case

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, grails-2.0

I have 800+ unit test cases in my Grails application. I'm using below mentioned configuration for my Grails App

```
app.grails.version=2.4.4
```

Below are the few lines from Run Configuration of Junit test cases

```
-Djava.library.path=./lib
-Dserver.ip=localhost
-Dserver.port=9090
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xverify:none
```

I'm running this application on an Ubuntu machine. Sometimes, while running the test cases, it is giving me Out Of Memory error like below and many more:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
>   org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:37)
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.engine.SimpleMapEntityPersister$1.query(SimpleMapEntityPersister.groovy:126)`
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.engine.SimpleMapEntityPersister.getPropertyIndexer(SimpleMapEntityPersister.groovy:90)
>        org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery$_closure35.doCall(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:431)
>        org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeSubQueryInternal(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:700)
>       org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeSubQuery(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:676)
>       org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeQuery(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:63)
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.list(Query.java:542)
>   grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(CriteriaBuilder.java:329)

I took a Sampler and Profiler memory management test but they could not help much. Also in each test case Groovy class, I'm using `@Before` and `@After` annotation to reduce Permanent Generation.

Is there anything I'm missing? I want to reduce PermGen and to get rid of Out Of Memory error permanently.

Comment: Grails 2.4.4  using groovy 2.3.7 internally So there is no chance of memory leakage here!!

Comment: what version of Java?

Comment: java version:-  7

Comment: Hint: never put more information into comments; always update your question instead. And I dont get your first comment. When using other peoples libraries, there is always a (maybe very small) chance of that product giving memory leaks.